# Order of libraries passed to linker

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ubuntu-14.04, suse

At one point in time in my life the order of libraries that one passed to the gcc mattered. You pass gcc the list of libraries from the most to least dependant. For example consider the following source code:

testlib.c

```
include <math.h>

double proxy_sqrt(double x)
{
    return sqrt(x);
}
```

testlib.h

```
double proxy_sqrt(double);
```

use-testlib.c

```
#include "testlib.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    proxy_sqrt(36);
    return 0;
}
```

Then to compile and link:

```
gcc -c -o testlib.o testlib.c
ar rvs testlib.a testlib.o
gcc -o use-testlib use-testlib.c testlib.a -lm
```

Note that the last step the most to least dependent ordering is used.

But this (invalid?) order works on SLES12

```
gcc -o use-testlib use-testlib.c -lm testlib.a
```

but fails on Ubuntu 14.04....

```
gcc -o use-testlib use-testlib.c -lm testlib.a
testlib.a(testlib.o): In function `proxy_sqrt':
testlib.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone know why?

Verbose output from the 2 compilers is shown at the links below:

sles12

http://pastebin.com/sKe8B7V9

ubuntu14.04

http://pastebin.com/vf8fTaE2

Comment: Are you *sure* that's how you create the `testlib.o` object file? Should you not use the `-c` flag there?

Comment: As for your problem, what linker are you using on the different platforms, especially what *version* is it?

Comment: Use the `-v` flag to see how your linker is really getting invoked. You may find that `libm` is a default on one system and not on the other....

Comment: @CarlNorum Happens with other libraries as well. This is a simplified example of the real case.

Comment: @sashang, you should still find out what your linker is really doing.

Comment: Does `gcc -o use-testlib use-testlib.c testlib.a` (without math lib) works on SLES12 ? Because then it may be that the math lib is a default lib on SLES12 and it would explain why the order does not matter.

Comment: @JoëlHecht: no it doesn't link without -lm

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's collect2. See the verbose output in the links above.

Comment: @CarlNorum: it's linkers on sles12 and ubuntu14.04

Comment: `collect2` is part of the `gcc` front-end program, it calls the `ld` program. Since both are Linux systems I assume that both will use the GNU linker, but what *versions* of it? If you type e.g. `ld --version` in both systems, do the versions differ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: version 2.24 on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the differences in the linker (`collect2`) commands and the `--as-needed` and `--no-as-needed` options:

> SLES 12

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/collect2 --build-id --eh-frame-hdr \
    -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker … /tmp/ccgoQd94.o -lm testlib.a -lgcc \
    --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s \
    --no-as-needed /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/crtend.o \
    /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

> Ubuntu 14

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr \
    -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker … \
    /tmp/cciheQTH.o -lm testlib.a -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s \
    --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed \
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o \
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

The use of `--as-needed` at the start of the options for Ubuntu 14 changes the behaviour of things compared to SLES 12.  Reputedly, it is to make things easier.  I remain to be convinced — it just seems to give new ways for code to break when moved.

Comment: So if I am interpreting the man page correctly then --as-needed causes the link to fail because it sees the library libm before the library testlib.a that uses a symbol from libm, and therefore does not emit the DT_NEEDED tag, whose absence makes that library (libm) not needed. Then it reads testlib.a and finds the symbol 'sqrt' and doesn't look in libm (because it was not marked DT_NEEDED) and decides there is nothing that can resolve it therefore the link fails.

Comment: Both platforms are right; they're just different.  It remains true that if you list the libraries in the correct sequence (so that earlier libraries call functions in later libraries and not vice versa, and avoid referential loops between libraries), then the link will work if you list object files first and then the libraries in sequence.  Any other sequencing of the object files and libraries is prone to failure on some platform or another.  Your analysis of DT_NEEDED sounds correct — it certainly describes what you see and I've experienced when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

grouping of the libraries results in every library in the group being repeatedly searched until no more references are resolved.

without grouping, each library is only searched once in left to right order.

(a library name can be repeated on the command line to help with this kind of problem)

From the man page for the gcc linker: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld

--start-group archives --end-group

The archives should be a list of archive files. They may be either explicit file names, or -l options.

The specified archives are searched repeatedly until no new undefined references are created. Normally, an archive is searched only once in the order that it is specified on the command line. If a symbol in that archive is needed to resolve an undefined symbol referred to by an object in an archive that appears later on the command line, the linker would not be able to resolve that reference. By grouping the archives, they all be searched repeatedly until all possible references are resolved.

Using this option has a significant performance cost. It is best to use it only when there are unavoidable circular references between two or more archives.